# why does IE need for me to click twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have this jQuery

```
    $('.billing_info').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(($('.shipping_selection').length) > 0){
            if ($('.shipping_selection:checked').length == 0){
                $('.hide_error').show();
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".hide_error").offset().top }, "slow");
                $(".hide_error").effect("highlight", {}, 4000);
                return false;
            }else{
                $('.billing_info').unbind("click");
                $('.billing_info').click();
            }   
        }else{
            $('.billing_info').unbind("click");
            $('.billing_info').click();
        }
    });
```

which works awesome in all browsers except in IE. I'm using IE8 and the user needs to click the button twice for the button to accept the click event even if there is one radio button $('.shipping_selection') clicked

Comment: Can you debug it and see what IE is doing in each of those clicks? Does the event handler fire twice? Is the click being caught by some other element on the page?

Comment: is there a firebug type tool that i can use, that i can do console.log

Comment: What is .billing_info an `<input type="submit" />`? Add your HTML so we can get the full picture.

Comment: <input type="submit" value="Next Step" class="bigbutton billing_info">

Comment: one second i will add more more

Comment: IE has an equivalent to Firebug: [IE8 Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565622(v=vs.85).aspx) (no comment on which is easier to use). And please edit your question to add more info, don't put it in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a bit of refactoring would help. Only prevent default when you need to, otherwise let the function pass through to the default submit event.

```
$('.billing_info').click(function(e){
    if(($('.shipping_selection').length) > 0 && $('.shipping_selection:checked').length == 0){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.hide_error').show();
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".hide_error").offset().top }, "slow");
            $(".hide_error").effect("highlight", {}, 4000);
            return false;
    }
});
```